# Error using rascal Java15 grammar

Tags: rascal

I tried to parse some Java Code using the Java15 grammar of Rascal. However, it does not accept the declaration of local variable of parameterized types. In more details:

- it **does not** recognize `List<String> files = ...`
- it recognizes `final List<String> files = ...`
- it recognizes `List<String, String> files = ...`

It seems to me that the problem is related to some ambiguity involving LocalVarDecStatements and expressions involving "<" and ">". However, I could not figure out how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not one to say "works for me", but it does :-) See:

```
rascal>import lang::java::\syntax::Java15;
ok
rascal>import ParseTree;
ok
rascal>parse(#LocalVarDec, "List\<String\> files = null")
LocalVarDec: (LocalVarDec) `List<String> files = null`
```

Could you provide the example or a simplified example which has the error in it?

Comment: That is interesting. When I run your example using the console, it also works for me. But when I run the parser using a specific file, it does not work. Sample file: https://github.com/refactoring-towards-language-evolution/rascal-Java8/blob/master/testes/LambdaSample.java. Note that we are working with a Java8 extension of your grammar. But I am quite sure that we did not change the LocalVarDec definition. By the way, when we finish the Java8 grammar, we would be happy to share with you.

Comment: It's entirely possible that syntax features interact, leading to parse errors if the extensions for java 8 use constraints like !>>. These extensions can make the parser behave in a way which is not strictly "context free". Please share the grammar somehow and we'll have a look.

Comment: The grammar is available here: (https://github.com/refactoring-towards-language-evolution/rascal-Java8/blob/master/src/Java18.rsc). Currently, it supports default methods in interfaces, try with resources, and multi-catches. A very experimental version of lambda expressions is also available. If you prefer, we have a Rascal project with some testes as well: (https://github.com/refactoring-towards-language-evolution/rascal-Java8). Please, let me know if you have any problems to access our gramar or Rascal project.

Comment: Dear @jurgenv, I fixed this particular problem changing the definition of ExpressionStatement. Instead of any valid expression, I change it to exclude relational expressions (such as >, <, and so on). I am not sure what kind of side effect might lead, but it fixed the problem mention above using. I used the following syntax: `syntax Stm = ... | exprStm : NonRelExpr` and `syntax NonRelExpr = Expr!gt!ltEq!lt!gtEq!eq!notEq;`

Comment: I see. The introduction of `->` lambdas makes the grammar ambiguous indeed because of the comparisons, but you've now removed some legal derivations. I'd probably add this `"-" !>> "\>"` to all occurrences of "-" in the grammar, such that the "->" operator can not be split into "-" and ">" anymore, and remove the `NonRelExpr` again. It's a careful job this grammar writing; understand that with Rascal all disambiguation which is done by Java has to be declared explicitly to avoid confusion. This can be hard.

Comment: Note that I've not seen any ambiguous trees yet, so I might be off on this one, but it's something like this. Have you tried the `Ambiguity` module to `diagnose` the ambiguous trees. It's a rough interface, but can give some reasonably good hints about what's going on.

Comment: thanks very much. I decided to write a Java8 parser in Rascal "from the ground", using as reference the syntax specification (from Oracle) and an existing ANTLR grammar (+ some definitions of the Rascal Java15 grammar). Currently it recognizes almost 95% of a test suite (more or less 2000 Java files from Cassandra and jEdit). It is available at https://github.com/refactoring-towards-language-evolution/rascal-Java8/blob/master/src/lang/java/syntax/Java18.rsc. Next week I will improve that grammar, which currently does not make use of all Rascal features for disambiguation .

Comment: Ok that's great! I'll have a look. We're working on a rascal archive for people to easily reuse their code. This would be an excellent example.